# Easiest way to keep my Python script open for a week?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a Python script which connects to Twitter via its Streaming API, and which then outputs tweets which contain the specified keywords into a CSV file.

I am interested in keeping this script running for about a week or so, so that I can track how many times the keywords of interest are mentioned during that one-week period.

I currently start the script via the command line on my Windows 7 machine. Problem is, it's impractical for me to keep my laptop (and hence the script) running for a week, without interruptions. I am a college student, and often take my laptop to class, which involves shutting down the laptop, and killing the process.

What's the easiest way for me to accomplish what I want, i.e. keep the script alive for a week or so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not really a programming question, and maybe better suited for superuser to help you find a decent hosting for you project. Consider Google Apps.

Comment: Don't you have access to a linux server at school? There may be some restrictions to what you can run there, but assumming you abide by the school rules, you should be able to keep the script running indefinitely. In fact, you could regularly have the server e-mail you the csv, so that you don't need to log onto the server.

Comment: Can you afford to buy a used computer for $25, or find someone with an ancient computer they don't use anymore than they're willing to part with for free, and leave that running 24/7 in your dorm room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that your best option is to use some other machine.

There are a number of avenues you can pursue

- Your college may have a server with user accounts that you can log in to. This may be a unix account but that will almost certainly have python installed on it, though if you are using specialty libraries, those may have to be installed.
- You can get a free [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) account. This is a cloud based virtual machine that you can run Windows or Linux on and it lasts a year.
- Borrow a friend's desktop ( if anyone has those anymore ) to run this.
- You may be able to find an other machine to get an account on.

Good luck! I hope your project turns out.

Answer (score 1):

A raspberry pi is convenient for these types of things, maybe consider getting one should this situation arise in the future. Other than that I'd try to get permission from someone with an unused desktop computer to run it there (maybe your family has an old windows computer that's unusable now but which someone can boot up an ubuntu live cd on and let you ssh into it).